# Invoke-RestMethod not recognizing XML with Byte Order Mark served by SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to come up with a minimally simple yet reliable PowerShell script to scrape out data from InfoPath documents in SharePoint.  So far, it's going well.  Invoke-RestMethod works well using SharePoint's RSS feeds, and decodes things properly.  But things get a little strange when I download the actual file.  On the InfoPath-saved files in my document library, Invoke-RestMethod returns does not properly infer that the response is an XML document.  In these cases, I notice there is a three-character Unicode BOM at the beginning of the response.  If I strip it off and cast it to [xml] as in the following snippet, things work just fine.

```
$infoPathRequest = '{0}?NoRedirect=true&OpenIn=PreferClient' -f $infoPathFile;    
$infoPathForm = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $infoPathRequest -UseDefaultCredentials)

#Sometimes Invoke-RestMethod gets confused by the BOM on the XML document.
#In that case, strip it off and convert it.
if ($infoPathForm.GetType().Name -eq "String") {
    $infoPathForm = [xml]$infoPathForm.Substring(3);    
}
```

But what I would much rather like is for Invoke-RestMethod to simply properly detect that the response is XML and load it as such.  If I try to cast the response to [xml] without stripping the BOM, I get a `Cannot convert value ï»¿<?xml version="1...` error.

My theory is that since SharePoint isn't sending a response header saying the charset is utf-8 (it isn't, I checked), Invoke-RestMethod is falling back to ASCII, perhaps?  Is there a cleaner way for me to get Invoke-RestMethod to properly detect the content type?  I didn't see anything in the docs where I could force it to infer a charset of UTF-8.  I have a nagging feeling that this is the best I will be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/807794/invoke-webrequest-ignores-content-encoding) and has been reported for `Invoke-WebRequest` but it isn't surprising that the bug is also in `Invoke-RestMethod` as these two commands share a common core.  Please vote on the bug at the link provided.  There are also a couple of workarounds mentioned in the details of the bug.

Comment: For some reason the page that the bug link points to is not publicly visible

Comment: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11088009-invoke-webrequest-ignores-content-encoding seems to be the updated replacement link?